# Modifying a numpy array from multiple processes without locks

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a big *numpy.array* shared across multiple processes (created using *pool.map*), and I want each process to modify a different part of the array. Since there is no 2 processes that can modify the same part of the array, I can get away without using any locks, and therefore without slowing down the code. In my understanding, I should therefore use *multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray* instead of *multiprocessing.Array*.

However, when I run the following toy example with only 1 process, the writing time  is *0.05s*. When I run the same code with 32 processes (the multiprocessing.cpu_count() of my machine), the writing time is *1.8s*. I get the same numbers when I use *multiprocessing.Array*. It seems to imply that the processes still lock the whole array while writing. Is there any way I can avoid that and speed things up?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray


def modify_array(i):
    arr = np.frombuffer(np_x, dtype=np.float32).reshape(np_x_shape)

    start_time_local = time.perf_counter()

    # Do some processing, each process write to a different row
    for j in range(100):
        arr[i, ...] = i

    print(f"Writting time {time.perf_counter() - start_time_local}")

def pool_initializer(X, X_shape):
    global np_x
    np_x = X
    global np_x_shape
    np_x_shape = X_shape


if __name__ == "__main__":

    n_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # 1

    # Original numpy array
    array_shape = (80, 1920 * 1080 * 3)
    data = np.ones(array_shape, dtype=np.float32)

    # Allocate the shared Array
    X = RawArray('i', np.array(array_shape).prod().item())
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X, dtype=np.float32).reshape(array_shape)

    # Copy data to the shared array
    np.copyto(X_np, data)

    # Create the processes
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_processes, initializer=pool_initializer, initargs=(X, array_shape)) as pool:
        pool.map(modify_array, range(array_shape[0]))
```

Comment: Have you considered the newer `multiprocessing.shared_memory`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: Yes, I also tried using shared_memory. I get similar performances as with RawArray -  0.05s for 1 process and 1.8s for 32 processes.

Comment: `shared_memory` and `RawArray` work in a very similar manner, and should be equally fast. Is your example with 1 process just using the main process and not using `Pool` at all? it seems like you have a work function that is not taking long enough to overcome the overhead of multiprocessing.

Comment: Yes, `shared_memory` and `RawArray` are also equally fast in my toy example. For the 1 process example, I am also using `Pool`. As you can see in the code I shared, I'm measuring the writing time inside the child processes, so it should not be affected by the overhead of multiprocessing.

Comment: When you use `multiprocessing.Array` it does *not* automatically lock amything. First of all you can specify the *lock=False* argument when creating the array and there will be no support for locking and you will be creating a `RawArray`. But even if you don't do that, then you have to do something more or less the equivalent of `with my_shared_array.get_lock(): ... # do something` in order to serialize access.

Comment: This is also what I thought, but I don't know why it is so slow to write from multiple processes in the same shared array then.

Comment: AFAICT, multiprocessing always use pickling for inter-process communication (IPC) and pickling is slow. Not to mention IPC has a significant latency so if your lock is contended, then you have to pay for the latency of each operation of the long dependency chain. Multiprocessing is a mess in Python. Multithreading with the GIL make it mostly useless. Overall, parallel computing in Python is a mess. That being said, you can use Numba and Cython so to write multithreaded application that can disable the GIL temporarily. THis generally gives good performance, especially Numba.

Comment: @JérômeRichard What is being passed is a shared array -- nothing has to be pickled, Also, what is being shown as the "writing time" does not include any overhead in passing the array to `modify_array` -- even if it had to be pickled.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the problem is that for the operation you are performing 1000 times, i.e. `arr[i, ...] = i`, `numpy`, which is implemented in the C language, `numpy` can perform the operation very fast and efficiently and therefore using multiprocessing, which carries with it overhead, is non-productive. Thus the increased writing times you see for each pool process when your pool size is 32 is the result of contention for the CPU that exists among the pool processes (you do have other processes running on your computer, right?) but you will find that the actual total elapsed time for updating the shared array is only slightly more the time doing the update without using multiprocessing. I reduced the array size so that the number of  rows is only 4 and ran your code performing the update of all rows serially (elapsed time = .45s), using one pool process (elapsed time: .63s) and 4 pool processes (elapsed time: .83s).

I then modified the `numpy` operation you are performing making it a bit more complex:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray


def modify_array(i):
    arr = np.frombuffer(np_x, dtype=np.float32).reshape(np_x_shape)

    start_time_local = time.perf_counter()

    # Do some processing, each process write to a different row
    for j in range(np_x_shape[1]):
        arr[i, j] += j
        
    print(f"Writting time {time.perf_counter() - start_time_local}")

def pool_initializer(X, X_shape):
    global np_x
    np_x = X
    global np_x_shape
    np_x_shape = X_shape

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Original numpy array
    array_shape = (4, 1920 * 1080 * 3)
    np_x_shape = array_shape
    data = np.ones(array_shape, dtype=np.float32)

    # Allocate the shared Array
    X = RawArray('i', np.array(array_shape).prod().item())
    np_x = X
    X_np = np.frombuffer(X, dtype=np.float32).reshape(array_shape)

    # Copy data to the shared array
    np.copyto(X_np, data)

    start_time_local = time.time()
    for i in range(4):
        modify_array(i)
    print(f"Total elapsed time {time.time() - start_time_local} for serial processing.")

    for n_processes in (1, 4):
        # Create the processes
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_processes, initializer=pool_initializer, initargs=(X, array_shape)) as pool:
            start_time_local = time.time()
            pool.map(modify_array, range(array_shape[0]))
            print(f"Total elapsed time {time.time() - start_time_local} for {n_processes} processes.")
```

Prints:

```None
Writting time 15.5535143
Writting time 15.374427999999998
Writting time 15.145224700000004
Writting time 14.993671000000006
Total elapsed time 61.06799650192261 for serial processing.
Writting time 15.058930599999998
Writting time 15.1148154
Writting time 15.240018899999999
Writting time 15.161053899999999
Total elapsed time 60.78710079193115 for 1 processes.
Writting time 21.2329833
Writting time 21.437830299999998
Writting time 21.4692298
Writting time 21.533945199999998
Total elapsed time 21.806999921798706 for 4 processes.
```

The "writing times" and total elapsed time for both serial processing and using a pool size is more or less the same. For a pool size of 4, we do see that the writing times increase by approximately 50%. I believe this is because of contention among the processes for getting CPU access (I only have 4 cores and there are, of course, other processes running in the desktop). But, the total elapsed time is reduced by a factor of (approximately) 3.

I conclude that this particular operation you are performing is already being implemented by `numpy` efficiently and is not a good candidate for multiprocessing, but that does not rule of the use of multiprocessing for other `numpy` operations.